# is the precedence of operator ignored in 'if' conditions

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I'v a following code:

```
void main()
{
  int k, x, y, z;
  printf("\nExperiment 1:");
  x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
  k = x++ || y++ && z++;
  printf("\nx = %d, y = %d, z = %d and k = %d\n", x, y, z, k);
  printf("\nExperiment 2:");
  x = 1, y = 0, z = 0;
  k = x++ || y++ && z++;
  printf("\nx = %d, y = %d, z = %d and k = %d\n", x, y, z, k);
}
```

The output:

Experiment 1:
x = 1, y = 1, z = 0 and k = 0

Experiment 2:
x = 2, y = 0, z = 0 and k = 1

What I've understood is:
For the expression to be true, either left side or right side of '||' has to be non-zero. It starts from left. If left is non-zero, it doesn't evaluate further. If it is zero, it starts on right side. On right we have '&&'. So, we again start from left side of && and in case it is zero, the expression cannot be true and it doesn't proceed. Otherwise it evaluates the right side of '&&'

My assumption was operator && has higher precedence. So, both of its arguments should have been evaluated and then && should have been applied over it followed by evaluation of both arguments of ||.

Is compiler optimizing itself? I've used Visual Studio TC compilar with Optimization disabled.

Comment: These are not "if conditions", by the way. They're simply expressions, using boolean operators and post-increment operators.

Comment: Just because && has tighter precedence does not mean `k = x++ || (y++ && z++)` will execute the && before the ||. This is called short-circuiting and very well known. You even mention it yourself. Imagine: `k = x++ || f(&y,&z)` where f() returns `(*y)++ && (*z)++`. It is functionally aequivalent to your code.

Comment: @Matthias: indeed; `++` has even higher precedence than `&&`; we don't expect the post-incrementing to happen before everything else just because of precedence...

Comment: Where did you pick up the `void main()`? It should be `int main(void)` in almost all circumstances.

Comment: Just to reinforce the concept with slightly different wording: precedence only controls grouping of operators and operands.  It *does not* control order of evaluation.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is covered in C11 by `§6.5.14 Logical OR operator` (my emphasis)

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, **the || operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation**; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
>   a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
>   operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.**

Answer (score 4):

So the expression

```
k = x++ || y++ && z++;
```

is interpreted as (due to precendence rules):

```
k = x++ || (y++ && z++);
```

In Experiement 1, we have `x = y = z = 0;`.

In Experiement 2, we have `x = 1, y = z = 0;`.

So, the right-hand side expression stops after evaluating `y++`, since the value of that is 0 and thus the boolean and cannot become true.